# Should Cache-Control max-age be set if marked public?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I was trying to figure out the best cache headers for my site and couldn't find a good resource about setting both `max-age` and `public`.

In my situation I have a number of files where I am not worried about them expiring, if I were to set max-age it would probably be a month or year.  But my question is, should the `max-age` be omitted, and just specify `Cache-Control: public`?  Isn't that essentially saying "cache for as long as you can"?

**TL;DR** Are there any advantages/disadvantages to setting `max-age` if `public` is set and the objects have an indefinite expiry time?

Answer (score 1):

`Cache-Control: public` means that the resource is publicly available, and thus may be put in cache available to several users (such as a corporate Internet proxy). It has nothing to do with how long a resource may be cached. See [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.1).